# How to disable mobile keyboard action key using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I just need to **disable** the **action button** while the search query is empty. I'm not sure if this is possible with native Flutter.

Does this need to be done with each platform specifically? (iOS / Android)

[image]

Comment: I don't get your question that well. If you want to close the keyboard when the text field is empty, then this might be helpful: https://speakerdeck.com/iampawan/become-a-pro-flutter-developer?slide=49 just you need to do some custom changes. Just call the **_dismissKeyboard()** function when the text field is empty.

Comment: @ChinkySight I just want to disable the ability to dismiss the keyboard by tapping search for instance

Comment: if you want to dismiss the keyboard then my first comment will help you 

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `FocusNode` to your `TextFormField` and request focus for it if the user presses the submit button on the keyboard when the field is empty. Here is a complete example:

```
class KeyboardKeeper60943209 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyboardKeeper60943209State createState() => _KeyboardKeeper60943209State();
}

class _KeyboardKeeper60943209State extends State<KeyboardKeeper60943209> {
  List<String> items = List.generate(20, (index) => 'item $index');
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                controller: _textEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  labelText: 'Search',
                  hasFloatingPlaceholder: false,
                ),
                // This is the key part
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  if(value == ''){
                    _focusNode.requestFocus();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(onPressed: search, child: Text('Search'))
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(items[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(items[index]),
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void search(){
    print('search');
  }
}
```

Comment: So this will cause the search button to become inactive ? Or will it just refocus the textfield widget, leaving the search button blue?

Comment: Just to see if I understand correctly. What you really want to do is have the devices keyboard submit button disabled?

Comment: Yes correct! It doesn't seem like something that I can do through Flutter. I think I need to specify this in the iOS and Android files.

If you had a Flutter solution I'd be so happy though!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

You can create a new focus:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode())
```

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: ....,    
      )
    )
  )
}
```

The other option is to release the existing focus:

```
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
    currentFocus.unfocus();
}
```

There is also a package: keyboard_dismisser

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I made the question clear enough. I don't need to dismiss the keyboard, I'm trying to disable the **search button** I don't want the user to be able to tap search until they have entered a query

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                  readOnly: true,
                  showCursor: false,
                  controller: consName,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter Name',
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Very Simple & Easy Use "readOnly: true" for disabling keyboard and if you don't want pointer or cursor then "showCursor: false". That's it, hope this'll work. Eat Sleep Workout Code Repeat. Happy Coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use **`textInputAction: TextInputAction.none`** on the TextField.

Comment: This does not work for iOS (only Android) and in the Android case, it removes the action entirely, and does not disable the button as the question is asking.